# Can there be a collision at node zero in a HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I know that getForNullKey() resolves the null key entries in a HashMap. But will there be a scenario that there are collisions at node 0 of the HashMap. If there are multiple objects whose hashcode return zero, will they be stored in the linked list at node zero? Does getForNullKey() help in obtaining the output

```
private V getForNullKey() {
  for (Entry<K,V> e = table[0]; e != null; e = e.next) {
      if (e.key == null)
         return e.value;
 }
 return null;
}
```

I am a bit confused about wht the e.value returns.

EDIT:

The doubt which I have is:Suppose we peek into a HashMap
     node no 4->["Key1"|1234|"Value1"|Point to next node]-->   ["Key2"|12345|"Value2"|Point to next node]

is the picture at node 4 which has collision owing  to two keys that ended up in the same node.

Can such a thing happen at node zero as well ? I know how "Value2" at node 4 can be reached using get().

But can  getForNullKey()  help in getting to the multiple entries at node zero..if that happens. Still learning HashMap hence a curious doubt :)

Comment: This question is unclear... `e.value` is the value for the entry `e`, but it's not clear what that has to do with anything else. Yes, entries with a hash code of 0 will be stored in the first bucket in the table. Yes, the entry corresponding with a null key would also be stored in that bucket.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I assume I'm not the first to make [this joke](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573773/is-it-possible-to-trick-this-windowsidentity-code-into-using-the-wrong-user#comment54926194_33573773). ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Can't say I've heard that one. I'm fond of http://memegenerator.net/instance/62989260 though...

Comment: @JonSkeet: I have elaborated my question. Could you please have a look.

Comment: It's still really not clear. Yes, there can be multiple entries in the first node of the table - which is why `getForNullKey` has a loop in it. I don't know what you mean by "can `getForNullKey` help in getting to the multiple entries at node zero" - `getForNullKey` gets the value associated with the null key, and that's *all* it does.

Comment: It would be surprising if a node (bucket) with index 0 should be different from all the rest. The fact that the null key also "hashes" into this bucket is just convenient, because that bucket is always there, if any.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the confirmation. For a non zero node scenario, the check on collision is (1) Is the Hashcode of the key passed and the object in the HashMap the same (2) If hashcode same, check the objects using equals method and provide the value (3) If hashcode not same, move to the next entry pointed by the linked list. For a zero node scenario, too this will be possible. Only the hashcodes are guaranteed to be same in this case. Hence the equals method will be used to check the objects and return values. That is handled by getForNullKey. This is my understanding.

Comment: @SusanMiller: No, the hashcodes *aren't* guaranteed to be the same. There can be non-zero hashcodes which still end up in the same bucket. `getForNullKey` only checks whether the key is `null` rather than checking the hashcode because that's all that's required - it's not like there could be entries with a null key but a different hashcode...

Comment: @JonSkeet I have read that Hashcode of null key is zero. So at least that is guaranteed. Would you agree?

Comment: @SusanMiller: Yes, but that's not the same as what you claimed which was that entries in the zero node are guaranteed to have the same hash code.

Comment: @JonSkeet Now things are clear :)